# Is there any way to set enable by default a permission on the registerUserPermissions hook?

Tags: permissions

When I create a permission using the registerUserPermissions hook I would like everyone, in all user groups have access to that permission. An admin has to take an explicit step to restrict access to that pemission. Something like this:

```
/**
 * @return array
 */
public function registerUserPermissions()
{
    return array(
        'my-permission' => array(
            'label' => Craft::t('Edit Settings'),
            //****ENABLE BY DEFAULT****
            'enable'=> true
        ),
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's not a native way to do this, but you might want to consider adding it as a [feature request](http://feedback.craftcms.com).

In the meantime, you might be able to work around it a bit with some custom JS in the control panel and using something like the [Control Panel JS](https://github.com/lindseydiloreto/craft-cpjs) plugin.